# Customized Pivot in sql 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do PIVOT on sql, where two columns value has to be aggreagated for each year.

The below code gives perfect result.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    SKU VARCHAR(10),
    YYMM VARCHAR(50),
    BRAND VARCHAR(50),
    AMT DECIMAL,  
    QTY INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
    SELECT '104591168', '2015-January', 'abott',200,    2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '104580709', '2016-January', 'GSK',159 , 2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '104720038', '2017-January', 'RANBAXCY',169, 2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '10467011A', '2018-January', 'abott',185,    2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '104590691', '2019-January', 'abott',256 ,   10


    SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT BRAND, sku, QTY, YYMM,AMT/QTY AS AVGPR
    FROM @TABLE
) AS src
PIVOT(
    sum(QTY)
    for [YYMM] IN( [2015-January], [2016-January], [2017-January] /* add other moneths here */ )
) AS Pivoted
```

and result look like
[image]

But how can i see AVGPR in same pivot way as like sum(qty).

when i tried like

code:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT BRAND, sku, QTY, YYMM
    FROM @TABLE
) AS src
PIVOT(
    sum(QTY),
    SUM(AVG)
    for [YYMM] IN( [2015-January], [2016-January], [2017-January] /* add other moneths here */ )
) AS Pivoted
```

i am getting Incorrect syntax error.

Please help

I have a data like this.

```
SKU YYMM    BRAND   Sales   Cost    QTY AVGPRICE
101110028   1/1/2017    ABOTT   15.7    5.73    1   15.7
101110028   2/1/2017    ABOTT   16.33   5.66    1   16.33
101110028   3/1/2017    ABOTT   31.2    11.34   2   15.6
```

and 
I AM TRYING TO DISPLAY LIKE THIS

```
        Sum of QTY          Sum of Avg Price        
BRAND   PNO 1/1/2017    2/1/2017    3/1/2017    1/1/2017    2/1/2017    3/1/2017
PAGID   101110028   0   2   1   15.7    16.33   15.6
```

Pivot on Quantity and then sum of avg for a same YYMM In a row

Comment: Edit the question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two pivots and `union all` for the result set in your comment

```
select *, Remarks = 'QTY'
from (select brand, sku, qty, yymm from @table) src
  pivot(sum(qty) for [yymm] in ( 
    [2015-January], [2016-January], [2017-January] /* add other months here */ 
  ) ) as Pivoted
union all
select *, Remarks = 'AVG'
from (select brand, sku, yymm,amt/qty as avgpr from @table) src
  pivot(sum(avgpr) for [yymm] in ( 
    [2015-January], [2016-January], [2017-January] /* add other months here */ 
  ) ) as Pivoted
order by brand, sku, remarks desc;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ORPF1616

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|  brand   |    sku    |   2015-January    |   2016-January   |   2017-January   | Remarks |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
| abott    | 104590691 | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             | QTY     |
| abott    | 104590691 | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             | AVG     |
| abott    | 104591168 | 2,0000000000000   | NULL             | NULL             | QTY     |
| abott    | 104591168 | 100,0000000000000 | NULL             | NULL             | AVG     |
| abott    | 10467011A | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             | QTY     |
| abott    | 10467011A | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             | AVG     |
| gsk      | 104580709 | NULL              | 2,0000000000000  | NULL             | QTY     |
| gsk      | 104580709 | NULL              | 79,5000000000000 | NULL             | AVG     |
| ranbaxcy | 104720038 | NULL              | NULL             | 2,0000000000000  | QTY     |
| ranbaxcy | 104720038 | NULL              | NULL             | 84,5000000000000 | AVG     |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT brand, sku,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YYMM = '2015-January' THEN QTY END) as [2015-January-QTY],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YYMM = '2015-January' THEN QTY END) as [2015-January-AVG],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YYMM = '2015-February' THEN QTY END) as [2015-February-QTY],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YYMM = '2015-February' THEN QTY END) as [2015-February-AVG],
       . . .
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY brand, sku;
```

Comment: Or will it be possible to do something like  BRAND PNO 1/1/2015 2/1/2015 3/1/2015 Remarks
Abott 101590282 4 2 1 QTY
Abott 101590282 30 26 28 AVG, so through remarks column we can identify.

Comment: but it gives error Incorrect syntax near '2017-August'.